# Linq to CSV Not ouputting data

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I am using linq to csv to output an entity to csv file. I have loop the source and there are definitely six records in the `PersonalDetails` variable.

```
public class PersonalDetails
{
    public string LineType { get; set; }
    public string EnquirerTitle { get; set; }
    public string ForeName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public string MobilePhone { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Employment { get; set; }
    public string Occupation { get; set; }
}

public Boolean CsvOutput(string filename, char delimnator)
    {
        try
        {
            CsvFileDescription outputFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
                SeparatorChar = delimnator, // tab delimited
                FirstLineHasColumnNames = false, // no column names in first record
                EnforceCsvColumnAttribute = true,
                FileCultureName = "nl-NL" // use formats used in The Netherlands
            };

            CsvContext cc = new CsvContext();
            IQueryable<tblapertureNetAppointment> _personadetails;

            var personalDetails = (from _appointments in _dal.apertureNetEntities.tblapertureNetAppointments
                                   select new PersonalDetails()
                                   {
                                       LineType = "Details",
                                       EnquirerTitle = "MR",
                                       ForeName = _appointments.CustomerFirstName,
                                       Surname = _appointments.CustomerLastName,
                                       Age = _appointments.age,
                                       DateOfBirth = _appointments.dob,
                                       MaritalStatus = "Single",
                                       HomePhone = "MobilePhone",
                                       Email = "david.buckley@aperture.uk.com",
                                       Address = _appointments.Address1 + "," + _appointments.Address2 + "," + _appointments.County + "," + _appointments.PostCode,
                                       Employment = "Developer",
                                       Occupation = "Yes"
                                   }).ToList();

            cc.Write(personalDetails,filename,outputFileDescription);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The file is created but there is no data in the actual file. When I debug there is records in the PersonalDetails

Comment: Do you need to dispose of the `CsvContext`?

Comment: as in .Dispose() not according to the docs there is a .write command which flushes

Comment: I'd suspect `cc.Write` method. You have to debug the programme to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @MaciejLos what avdvice or purpose does your answer give nothing ! mark down your response

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple method of writing csv

```
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
            string[][] rows = {
                                  {"abc", "cdf", "ghi"},
                                  {"jkl", "mno", "pqr"},
                                  {"stu", "vwx", "yz"}
                              };

            foreach (string[] row in rows)
            {
                writer.WriteLine(string.Join(",", row));
            }
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
```

Comment: that as no reference I am wanting to use linq 2 csv as is battle tested to work with thousands of records thanks for input but will down vote this

Comment: If you have a very large file I wouldn't use Linq the uses a lot of resources and is very slow.  Using a StreamWriter will significantly reduce the memory usage and probably run in 25% of the time of the Linq approach.

Comment: we are using entity framework through out the project and asked not to change so while i wish i could do it that way i cant so what way would be best with linq to used

Comment: linq is part of entity how the hell is stream writter part of entity their string manipulators